# Deactivate javascript-popup in IE6

Tags: ie6

i am totally new to Sharepoint 2010 and want to brand a Publishing-Site. Now, when i open the site in IE 6, a javascript alert pops up which says that one should upgrade to a newer browser.

Can i somehow get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
jo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<SharePoint:WarnOnUnsupportedBrowsers runat="server" />` tag from your Master Page, the message should't appear anymore.